# Show that the function $g(x) = x$ can intersect $f$ no more than once.

Tags: real-analysis

I was wondering how I can use  either Rolle's theorem or the Mean Value theorem to do this question:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Suppose that ${f}'(x)> 1$ for all $x$. Show that the function $g(x) = x$ can intersect $f$ no more than once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that there were two solutions $a$ and $b$. Consider the function $h(x) = f(x) - x$, so that

$$h(a) = 0 = h(b)$$

Now consider the fact that $h'(x) = f'(x) - 1$, but Rolle's theorem says something about the derivative of $h$.

Comment: Rolle's theorem says that $h'(c) = 0$ for any $c\in(a,b)$.

Comment: @AJR Rolle's theorem says that $h'(c) = 0$ for some $c$, not for any $c$. But if $h'(c) = 0$, what is $f'(c)$?

Comment: I have "any $c$" on my notes but I'll verify it with my lecturer. If $h'(c)=0$ then $f'(c)=1$. Hence we get a contradiction as we assumed $f'(x)>0$.